# Yup 0.32.0+ doesn't work with basic types - a workaround?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup

Since version 0.32 of Yup validation library, it's not anymore possible to define a basic schema like:

```
import yup from "yup";

interface LoginItem {
  loginName: string;
  password: string;
}

yup.object().defined().shape<LoginItem>({
  loginName: yup.string().defined(),
  password: yup.string().defined()
});
```

and have it compiled due to a TypeScript error:

```
Index signature is missing in type 'LoginItem'
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-chandrasekhar-7rywp?file=/src/test.ts

I couldn't find a workaround or a fix for this problem.

P.S. As it looked like a bug, I filed a [detailed report](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/1372) in the issue queue but it was closed w/o any resolution or helping references.